# Copying data to USB flash drive throws "Write Protect Error"

Tags: usb-storage

I have a USB flash drive, which I made bootable for use as an anti virus disk. After formatting the drive, whenever I copy some files to it, it shows an error:

> The disk cannot be written to because it is write protected. Please remove the write protection from the volume in drive \Device\Harddisk3\DR13.

[image: Write Protect Error]

Answer (score 2):

there many things you can try to get rid of this bug:

- try to locate a switch on the usb stick and use it (i guess you probably did that already)
- eject the usb stick and put it back in and look if this has fixed the problem

now to more advanced stuff:

1. format your usb stick using [low lever formatter](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Hard-Disk-Utils/HDD-Low-Level-Format-Tool.shtml)
2. the partition and all data on the stick is now lost you need to create the partiotion again: press win+r and run diskmgmt.msc. Select your drive choose ntfs and format it
3. check if it helped

so and the last thing you could try:

1. press win+r and run regedit
2. go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\
3. find the key "StorageDevicePolicies" if it does not exist create it
4. now create a new DWORD "WriteProtect" and set the value to 0

i hope this will solve your problem